# Is it a good practice to close my connection after Sequelize operations?

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, pool

currently I'm designing an app on top of Sequelize using NodeJS/TypeScript, and I'm wondering if it can cause performance issues not closing a connection.

For instance, in a micro service, I need data from 1 entity.

```js
const resolver = async (,,{db}) => {
  const entity1 = await db.models.Entity1.findOne()
  return entity1
}
```

Is it required to close the connection after having called `findOne`?

My understanding is that the following config defines a number of concurrent connections and idle is a parameter making the connection manager closing the connection of idle ones:

```js
module.exports = {
  development: {
    host: 'db.sqlite',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    pool: {
        max:5,
        min:0,
        idle:10000
    }
  },
  test: {
    host: 'test.sqlite',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    pool: {
        max:5,
        min:0,
        idle:10000
    }
  }
}
```

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sequelize maintains an internal [database connection pool](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/connection-pool.html), that's what the `pool` parameters are for, so this isn't necessary. Each call actually borrows a connection temporarily and then returns it to the pool when done.

Closing that connection manually may poison the pool and cause performance issues.

Comment: is the same applicable for lambda function as well ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74264495/nestjs-aws-lambda-sequelize-connection-pool

Answer (score 1):

If you don't close the Sequelize connection, the micro-service will still run until the connection got timed out (idle time pool parameter).. I suggest to close Sequelize connection, at least in micro-services..

Comment: and that will incur more costs (eg: lambda executing time).. and may cause a timeout of lambda service..

Comment: but I'm wondering if the connection isn't automatically closed by sequelize after the operation is done, I didn't notice timeouts for that specific use case