# NESTJS AWS Lambda & Sequelize connection pool

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, sequelize.js, nestjs

Since I have given the pool parameters as mentioned in the below code snippet, Is necessary to close the connection after each lambda invocation?

This aws lambda function is supposed to be triggered every minute, is the pool parameter only enough to close the connection?

```
export const databaseProviders = [
      {
        provide: 'vendorDB',
        useFactory: async (awsSecrets: AwsSecretsService) => {
          const { host, port, username, password, database } =
            await awsSecrets.getVendorDbConfig();
          const sequelize = new Sequelize({
            dialect: 'postgres',
            host,
            port,
            username,
            password,
            database,
            logging: true,
            pool: {
              max: 1,
              min: 0,
              idle: 1000,
            },
          });
          sequelize.addModels([VendorEntity]);
          //   await sequelize.sync();
          return sequelize;
        },
        inject: [AwsSecretsService],
      },
```

Comment: Do you mean "lambda" as in AWS Lambda?

Comment: yes. I just edited it

Comment: Lambda processes get shut down quite frequently so I'm not sure you'd have to worry about this. It is odd having a "pool" of 1 though. Why not just make a regular connection without pooling?

Comment: it's usages are there in below references. Kindly make a look into it

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/aws-lambda/

https://solidstudio.io/blog/aws-handle-database-connection

Answer (score 0):

injected db connection provider on necessary controllers.

```
constructor(
      private standardizeService: StandardizeService,
      @Inject('vendorDB') private readonly vendorDbConnection: any,
    ) {}
```

And after each lambda function is executed closeDbConnections function is called in the Finally statement.

```
    async closeDbConnections() {
      this.logger.log('Closing db connections');
      await this.vendorDbConnection.close();
    }
```